# Python list returns a unicode list

Tags: python, unicode

I can't seem to figure out why i'm getting a list returned in Unicode? In the code block below. I've tried print type(data_new) and it returns unicode list even though I'm trying to pull ASCII list.

Any guidance would be helpful.

---

---

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib

new_data = list()
sum = 0
url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
soupy = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(soupy)
    for p in soup:
p = re.compile('<span class="">(.*?)\</span>', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
p = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'comments'})
for row in p:
    text = ''.join(row.findAll(text=True))
    data = text.strip()
    new_data = data
    for i in new_data:
       sum + i
       print type(sum)
    else:
       print 'Your a terrible programmer: in the loop'             
if sum > 0:
    print 'Sum of numbers in file:', sum
else:
    print 'Your a terrible programmer: at the end'
```

Comment: Maybe one of the characters in the list cannot be expressed with ASCII ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

> Beautiful Soup automatically converts incoming documents to Unicode and outgoing documents to UTF-8.

So, to convert it from unicode to str use `str()`. But I guess you need `int()` to be able to do math with your numbers.

A bit cleaner example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
soupy = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(soupy)
rows = soup.findAll('span')
for row in rows:
    text = ''.join(row.findAll(text=True)) #<--- Here the text is unicode (1)
    data = int(text) #<--- to do math convert it to int (2)
    print data, type(data)
```

(1) `row.findAll(text=True)` returns you a list of unicode strings. Then you're joining elements of this list into a string: `''.join(your_list)`.
As a result you have a single unicode string which is expected.

(2) Sometimes people do `int(s.strip())`, but stripping is not needed as `int()` ignores leading and trailing white-spaces.

Comment: I always thought `join` performed on a byte string would yield a byte string, but it appears that if any of the elements to be joined is Unicode then the result is coerced to Unicode also. You taght me something new!

Answer (score 0):

That might have to do with the fact that BeautifulSoup uses class **NavigableString** for any bit of string that it returns in searches. That class is effectively unicode with some other properties.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring

You can always cast the result with **str()**, although in your case since you're adding up, you probably need to **int()** the value for that.